# Installation and configuration of DSPACE as Federated repository

Tags: repository, dspace

We already have dspace installed in various institutions across the country and want to deploy a centralized DSPACE repository as part of the federated repository. Contents from the branch repository will be synced to the centralized repository as soon as they are published. Contents from the centralized repository are then synced back to other branch repositories. Contents are not synced directly between branch repositories but only through the centralized repository.

Please we welcome ideas on how to achieve this as while we have various references including http://www.dlib.org/dlib/july06/tansley/07tansley.html and http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40276-0_21, we cant seem to make any headway.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the puzzle, pulling the contents of your branch repositories into the central one, you could look at this feature:

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization#XMLUIConfigurationandCustomization-HarvestingItemsfromXMLUIviaOAI-OREorOAI-PMH

The second challenge, having the branch repositories pull back changes/or new items from the central one, is quite another thing.

Unidirectional integrations where one repository is clearly the master record for a particular item is quite straightforward. However, bidirectional updates and managing the different cases and edge cases around changes happening in multiple places to the same items, is a big challenge.

So basically I'm advising you to reconsider your strategy and check if a scenario where one repository is always the master record for a particular item would also fit your use cases.